# Conditional Missing Values Imputation with the Frequency/Mode of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, missing-data

I have a dataframe with 'id', 'x1' columns. I would like replace the missing value in 'x1' with the most frequent value from 'x1' for the respective 'id'.

For instanace, missing value is present in 'x1', against 'id' = 1. The missing value replacement should be 'e', cause 'e' is the frequent/mode (3 times) value for 'id' = 1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5],
                   'x1': ['a', np.nan, 'b', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})
```

[image]

My approach was to first fetch the id for missing record.

```
df[df['x1'].isnull()==True]['id'].iloc[0]
```

Then using `value_counts` to fetch most frequent value from 'x1', where the 'id' `.isin` available in above output.

But, this looks computationally expensive and looking for an efficient solution.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a dictionary mapping each value in the column id to it's most frequent x1 value.

```
dict_id_to_x1_mode = df.groupby('id')['x1'].agg(pd.Series.mode).to_dict()
```

Then use the dictionary to map id to the most frequent x1 value where x1 is missing:

```
df.loc[df['x1'].isna(), 'x1'] = df.loc[df['x1'].isna(), 'id'].map(dict_id_to_x1_mode)
```

Comment: It works on the sample data. I got the following error in my actual use case. ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Do you get this error when you create the dictionary or when you use it to map the id column?
Can you provide example data to recreate the value error?

Comment: Yes, I get the error while creating the dictionary (first step). I am unable to reproduce the same error on the sample data at the moment.

Comment: Could it be caused by if you have multiple most common 'x1's for any one 'id', like in the example data below? This would give two most common id's (h and j) for x1=5: 
`df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5],
                   'x1': ['a', np.nan, 'b', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j']})`

Comment: Ah, that's a great observation. It is very much possible. Need to pick either of those values in such cases.

Comment: Another possible error is when both the id, and x1 values are missing.